# why we need to use jquery ".contents" method?

Tags: jquery

i see some jQuery code that use [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) method after `$(selector)`, then apply `.find`, ... methods to it. why?
what happen if we dont use `.contents()` method?

```
$(".selector").contents().find("a")...
$(".selector").find("a")...
$(".selector a")...
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/contents/ this is a real help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One main use of [contents](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) is when you use an iframe and want to access the nodes inside the `iframe`, then you can do something like `$('#myframe').contents().find(selector)`

What you have shared above are not the same

```
$(".selector").contents().find("a")//will return all descendant `a` element which are not the direct children of `selector`

//these to will return all descendant `a` elements including direct children
$(".selector").find("a")...
$(".selector a")...
```

Comment: thanks Arun, i write a [simple code](http://jsfiddle.net/wbxk56r1/) to see it in action.